# Summer 22 v55.0 Flow Deployment Error

Tags: visual-workflow, deployment, metadata, summer-22

A `Flow` metadata deployment to a Summer 22 (v55.0) org causes an error:

```
{!FlowScreenFieldName} (Screen Component) - Because the "{!FlowScreenFieldName}" screen field 
on the "{!FlowScreen}" screen is a section, the regionContainerType is required.
```

What is wrong with [`Flow`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) metadata if it is fully deployable to previous versions orgs and how to fix that?

Comment: The easiest fix to this issue would be to re-download the flow `metadata` using `55.0` API version and then it will be downloaded with all tags and structures as per that API version and you can deploy it further to other org again without getting error.

Answer (score 10):

The `regionContainerType` field of the [FlowScreenField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm#FlowScreenField) metadata component was introduced in API version `55.0`. Although it is not documented, when the component type is a `Section` this field is **required**.

To fix that simply manually add `regionContainerType` element with `SectionWithoutHeader` value to a `Flow` metadata file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Flow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  ...
  <screens>
    <name>FlowScreenName</name>
    <label>FlowScreen Label</label>
    <fields>
      <name>FlowScreenName_SectionN</name>
      <regionContainerType>SectionWithoutHeader</regionContainerType>
      ...
    <fields>
  </screens> 
</Flow>
```

The easier way would be retrieving `Flow` instances from updated to `Summer 22` sandbox instances if the metadata in the project repository matches the last deployed metadata. After that, all the flow screen sections will be automatically updated with `<regionContainerType>SectionWithoutHeader</regionContainerType>` element.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in how the metadata is retrieved. For example, in VS Code if you retrieve the flow metadata via the Org Browser the  value will not appear in the metadata. However, if you use the explorer or command line to pull the metadata the  value will be retrieved. This has worked for us and allowed us to continue deployment.

Comment: Be sure to check your version of the flow components in the package manifest used to retrieve the metadata (ie. may need to add `<version>56.0</version>`).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue: deploying a flow (metadata 57.0) to the spring 23 sandbox (v.55) and still got the strange error message "Property 'regionContainerType' not valid in version 53.0". In that case, I had to remove the tag

```
        <regionContainerType>SectionWithoutHeader</regionContainerType>
```